# Redirect rule not being followed

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have set up the following conf files for my apache site and enabled mod rewrite, but I'm having issues getting the rule to fire.  I'm fairly confident it's a missed configuration, but I'm not sure where it lies.  I have been experimenting with different configurations but can't find one that works

My apache2.conf file contains the following

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My 000-default.conf file contains the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/Foo/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /Baz/$1/Bar/$2/json

</VirtualHost>
```

If I go to :
http://localhost/Foo/sample/data

The error in the logs:

```
 File does not exist: /var/www/html/Foo/sample/data
```

However, if i manually go to /Baz/sample/Bar/data/json, I get a 200.

EDIT:
regex was wrong.  fixed but issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like maybe a missing bracket in your groups:

this:

`^/Foo/(A-Za-z0-9]+)/(A-Za-z0-9]+)$`

should be:

`^/Foo/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$`

This kind of error typically causes the server to complain about malformed configuration. Have you checked the server logs?

Comment: Fixed, but unfortunately the same issue still persists.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, since it was indeed an error on my part.  However, the final fix that made everything work for me was adding [PT] on the end of the rule. Without it it was trying to serve up a file, instead of trace back the url to the correct location.

Comment: More details about [PT] RewriteFlag can be found in [https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt)